# Avoid !important in new css file

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have to change an existing website so it becomes responsive. I don't have the possibility to start completely at the bottom, so I have created an extra CSS-file with some `@media`-queries to change the style depending on the width of the browser. I import this CSS-file through `@import` in the original CSS-file.

However, until now I have to write `!important` after each new style, otherwise the original file will just overrule and the original style is applied.

I thought about putting the original file between `@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }`, but that will just apply to everything and will therefore not display anything on devices <1200px.

How should I approach this? Should I keep using `!important` to overrule the original file, or is there another, probably better, approach?

Comment: Order in CSS includes matters.  Can you put the new CSS file after the original file?

Comment: Have you tried specificity instead?

Comment: @BrianHoover is right - if your media queries use the same selectors, but are loaded later, they'll "win".

Comment: It seems you have to add the new CSS file right after the first CSS file, in order to override it.

Comment: So, how do I approach this if I'm using `@import`? Should I actually `@import` the original file into the responsive one, instead of the other way around?

Comment: That would work well, yes.

Comment: @Rvervuurt A better aproach would be to load the original file in SASS and import the new CSS with media queries at the bottom of the page, but use an SASS import function. This will generate one complete CSS file thus reducing load times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you cascade it well, your responsive file could do well without `!important`.
Import your extra css-file after the original, and make sure selectors are as, or more, specific

Comment: I have imported it with `@import` (just added that to the question) and these have to stand completely in the top of the CSS-file. But as I understand, it might be better to just link to it in the `.phtml` file instead of in the CSS?

Comment: Of course, I can just import the original file in the responsive one, instead of the other way around. Would that be a good solution?

Comment: if they really HAVE to be on top, you can make all your selectors more specific by, for example, put `body` in front of every selector.

Comment: Loading the responsive file with the original imported at the top will do the trick :)

Comment: I chose your solution as correct, because after some consideration, this is the best and safest way when it comes to compatibility. Not using the `@import`, just to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Laurens King has it. Just append the new stylings at the end of the original CSS file. In that way, selectors of equal priority, e.g. class selectors, will be prioritized so that the one that is read last from the CSS file (i.e. the one in the appended section) will be given priority over any one of nominally equal priority read before it.

Comment: I mean Laurens Kling, not Laurens King !

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid it at all, do not use `!important`.

One way of avoiding it (if you can) is to make your css more specific than the original one is. For example if the original css has:

```
.some-class {color:#ff0000;}
```

then you can override it with:

```
#main .some-class{color:#0000ff;}
```

The second example is more specific than the first and therefore takes over from the first.

However if the original has any `!important` in it then you will likely need to use one of your own to override it.